# Text size is really big in one column of a table, really small in the others

Tags: html

My webpage does not have any css or text formatting, but the column text is coming out really huge, and in the worst place, too.

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Clinical Trials ID</th>
    <th>Official Title</th>
    <th>Contact Name</th>
    <th>Affiliation</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT01951326">NCT01951326</a></td>
    <td>A Randomized, Double Blind, Placebo-controlled, Multicenter, Parallel Group Study to Assess the Efficacy and Safety of Fixed-dose Combination RHB-104 in Subjects With Moderately to Severely Active Crohn's Disease</td>
    <td> Ira N Kalfus, MD</td>
    <td>RedHill Biopharma</td>
    <td> </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I can't post screenshots because I don't have enough rep

Thanks for your help

Comment: personally I dont access web-pages that i do not recognize. Can you please share a print screen of the web-page and add the html code to be able to further look into it?

Comment: Instead of the link, provide minimum reproducible code. Links are likely to change in future. Read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @user1578295 thanks for following up. Which column are you talking about in your question and what's the issue?

Comment: I updated the question. The problem column is the one with the most text (Official Title). It is turning up in huge text and every other column is tiny.

Comment: @user1578295 so what do you want to achieve?

Comment: you cannot publish an image, but you can use any image uploader and use that link. 
for me everything seems to be normal. The `th` of the table is fine as they are `th` and the first column its fine but it looks bigger as they are uppercase

Comment: AdityaSrivast I want the text in the columns to be the same size. Like font point size, not same width, because obviously one has more characters than others

Comment: Screenshot of my webpage https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-CaIJYsI7MZJMXQjYPOAnp1CzpIn4Q-E/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @user1578295 this seems like a problem related to browser. Which browser are you using?

Comment: AdityaSrivast I am using chrome. I'm guessing it doesn't look like my screenshot for anyone else? But still lots of people use chrome, so if it is a chrome specific thing I'd like to know how to avoid it

Comment: I think what I'll do is give the title its own row spanning all the rest of the columns

Answer (score 0):

I have probably got your error.

Your code seems to be missing a `meta` tag. Add this to your `head` tag:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And you'll be good to go.

Hope it helps. Cheers!!

Comment: Sorry, didn't seem to help

Comment: @user1578295 Unable to reproduce your error pal!  I could only reproduce your error in chrome by removing `meta` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Set a width for your td otherwise it will take all the space it gets free to take.

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Clinical Trials ID</th>
    <th>Official Title</th>
    <th>Contact Name</th>
    <th>Affiliation</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT01951326">NCT01951326</a></td>
    <td width="40%">A Randomized, Double Blind, Placebo-controlled, Multicenter, Parallel Group Study to Assess the Efficacy and Safety of Fixed-dose Combination RHB-104 in Subjects With Moderately to Severely Active Crohn's Disease</td>
    <td> Ira N Kalfus, MD</td>
    <td>RedHill Biopharma</td>
    <td> </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of CSS can fix this problem. The calc function might be especially useful:

```css
th{
    width: calc(100%/6);
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Clinical Trials ID</th>
    <th>Official Title</th>
    <th>Contact Name</th>
    <th>Affiliation</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>email</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT01951326">NCT01951326</a></td>
    <td>A Randomized, Double Blind, Placebo-controlled, Multicenter, Parallel Group Study to Assess the Efficacy and Safety of Fixed-dose Combination RHB-104 in Subjects With Moderately to Severely Active Crohn's Disease</td>
    <td> Ira N Kalfus, MD</td>
    <td>RedHill Biopharma</td>
    <td> </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```